# Spacy-nightly (spacy 2.0) issue with "thinc.extra.MaxViolation has wrong size"

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

After apparently successful installation of spacy-nightly (spacy-nightly-2.0.0a14) and english model (en_core_web_sm) I was still receiving error message during attempt to run it

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

ValueError: thinc.extra.search.MaxViolation has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 104, got 128
```

I tried to reinstall spacy and model as well and it has not help. Tried it again within new venv (Python 3.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is probably with thinc package, spacy-nightly needs thinc<6.9.0,>=6.8.1 but version 6.8.2 is causing some issues --> way how **to solve i**t is run command bellow **before** you install spacy-nightly

```
pip install thinc==6.8.1
```

After this everything works perfectly fine for me.

I found later on that I am not the only one facing this issue https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1374