# Import spaCy error

Tags: python, python-import, spacy

When I try to import [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) (for the first time), I get the follwoing error:

```
>>>import spacy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import en, de, zh, es, it, hu, fr, pt, nl, sv, fi, bn, he, nb, ja
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/en/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..language import Language
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .pipeline import DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer
  File "spacy/pipeline.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline (spacy/pipeline.cpp:16536)
    # coding: utf8
  File ".env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thinc/extra/search.pxd", line 72, in init spacy.syntax.beam_parser (spacy/syntax/beam_parser.cpp:20037)
ValueError: thinc.extra.search.MaxViolation has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

which recommends that I should recompile. What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Are you running 32-bit Python, by any chance?

Comment: Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544808/spacy-nightly-spacy-2-0-issue-with-thinc-extra-maxviolation-has-wrong-size/46544809#46544809

Comment: uninstall spacy and try pip3 install spacy==2.0

Answer (score 1):

It could be a version conflict with either `thinc` or `spacy`. It has been fixed in thinc v6.9.0!

I would suggest you uninstall by using `sudo pip uninstall thinc` or `sudo pip3 uninstall thinc` and reinstall the thinc version 6.9.0 provided here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/thinc

Comment: Can you please print the details such as your python version, spacy version installed, thinc version, OS etc

Comment: @WilliamSong Sorted out?

Comment: I installed them with pip. they must be newest. mac is 10.12.6, python is 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Issue is probably with thinc package, for spacy-nightly it needs thinc<6.9.0,>=6.8.1 but version 6.8.2 is causing some issues --> I think it is going to be the same issue for spacy; way how to solve it is run command bellow before you install spacy

```
pip install thinc==6.8.1
```